# sed s command not substituting

Tags: sed, android

This **sed** command

```
echo 'a' | sed 's/a/b/'
```

outputs

```
b a
```

Is this correct, or should it be generating just a *`b`*?

---

**Update**

I'm shelled into a Samsung Tab S2 running **Android 6.0.1** with **`adb shell`**

**`uname -a`** `Linux localhost 3.10.9-8374498 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 8 14:31:31 KST 2016 armv7l`

**`sed --version`** `This is not GNU sed version 9.0`

**`type sed`** `sed is a tracked alias for /system/bin/sed`

Comment: No it do‌esn't.

Comment: You should [edit] in your platform, `sed` version, `type sed`, and anything else that might narrow things down.

Comment: Does `printf '%s\n' "a" | sed 's/a/b/'` this command return the same result?

Comment: It outputs `b` on GNU sed. What kind of sed are you running?

Comment: related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40058/why-do-linux-commands-not-work-properly-on-android

Comment: try all of those to see if you have an alias or function that may change the behavior of echo or sed, or a binary with that name in a previous directory within PATH : `alias` ;  `set` ;  `declare -f` ;  `typeset -f` ;  `which echo` ;  `which sed` ;  `for i in $(echo "$PATH" | tr ':' ' '); do ls -l "$i"/echo "$i"/sed ; done`

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly expect the command `echo 'a' | sed 's/a/b/'` to print `b` on its own, and not print `b a` like your example.

Indeed, when I run that command on my nearest Android `adb shell`, I get the expected result:

```
$ adb shell
android:/ $ echo 'a' | sed 's/a/b/'
b
```

This is on a different device compared to yours (see the reference below for specific versions).

I can't think of what would generate the output `b a` (substitute, space, original). Before getting too deep, best make absolute sure that this is what you're really seeing -- type out the entire command exactly as written, key by key (no pasting).

If it really is generating that output, I can only imagine that coming from a bug present in your system. But which bug and where?

### Narrowing down the problem

First, make sure that your shell's pipeline is working as expected. Try piping a simple command with no arguments to another simple command with no arguments, for example `env | head`.

If you swap out your sed for `tr a b` or even `head` you will know whether it is specifically a problem with `sed`.

You can also try `sed` outside the pipeline. Run `sed` on its own as an interactive command and type input (like <kbd>a</kbd>) into it. Press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> when you're done to signal the end-of-file.

### A working environment

The shell is MirBSD KSH (`mksh`), `sed` is Toybox's sed command.

```
$ adb shell
android:/ $ sed --version
This is not GNU sed version 9.0
android:/ $ type sed
sed is a tracked alias for /system/bin/sed
android:/ $ ls -l /system/bin/sed
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root shell 6 2009-01-01 17:00 /system/bin/sed -> toybox
$ toybox --version
0.7.0-a324bde36bd6-android
$ echo $KSH_VERSION
@(#)MIRBSD KSH R52 2016/01/20
```

Comment: Pipeline seems to work for most part, but I do recall having unexpected behavior (with simple greps maybe) with this samsung and the asus tf700. I did root this device and installed busy box, but have since reflashed factory rom with kies using http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=SM-T810.

Comment: `echo 'a' | tr a b` shows `b`

Comment: `toybox --version` shows `-android` only (no version number or even whitespace, hyphen starts at newline).

Comment: `echo $KSH_VERSION` shows `@(#)MIRBSD KSH R50 2015/04/19`

Comment: It seems suspicious that toybox doesn't print a proper version. I'd definitely suspect that the toybox binary is the problem here. If you can confirm that the binary is the one the vendor ships (perhaps via checksum), then that's a bug to raise with the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

note: other answers welcome (i wont be accepting this)

I had the following **config** file that I wanted to set **`tls=true`**

> ip=192.168.1.1
>   port=08
>   **tls=false**

My workaround was as follows (only works b/c setting at tail of **config**)

```
tls=$(sed -n '/false/p' config)
sed -i '/false/d' config
echo ${tls/false/true} >> config
```

Answer (score -1):

```
we can do it by awk 

echo "a" | awk '{gsub("a","b",$1);print $1}'
b
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is why the sed command is not working